# tableView.setContentOffset not working when animated=False

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I call

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: CGFloat(startIndex * cellHeight)), animated: true)
```

the tableView loads then scrolls to the desired height of "startIndex * cellHeight" (this is essentially positioning a cell to the top of the tableview).

However, when I changed animated to false, it does not work. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where you are using this code? can you post all your related code?

Comment: Did you fix your issue?

Comment: I also have same issue. 

self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44), animated: false)

I don't know what's work it.

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am having the same question.